# How to show image hidding its direct link in php?

Tags: php, hotlinking

How can I create a php code that will process an ID for example and return corresponding image without providing client with actual image hotlink.

As implemented on link below the image is displayed in html page, but the **hot link** is hidden from client. Even opening the image in new window same link is shown not the original link to image.

This is definitely not implemented in .htaccess file as for each image URL with id corresponding image is rendered and is not a redirect to a single page.

http://www.imagesup.net/?di=15140291437113

Comment: Actually, when I click on that link it *downloads* the image, it's not even displaying it in the browser. It's all just done by mucking around with the HTTP referer and possible the Accept header. And as demonstrated, it doesn't really always work.

Comment: If it downloads image on click it shows this link directs to an image even though it is not a hotlink, this is exactly what is needed here. P.S it is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a basic way could be something like this

```
<?php

    // query to database mabye?
    $myPath = getImagePath($_GET['id']);

    // what kind of image file is that?
    $contentType = getContentType($myPath);

    // read file content
    $img = file_get_contents($myPath);

    // here you tell the browser what kind of image is that e.g. jpeg,png,gif...
    header("Content-Type: $contentType");

    echo $img;

?>
```

you need to define `getImagePath` and `getContentType` functions according to your needs.

Comment: This might be the answer, let me try before I choose your answer.

Comment: @XIMRX If you have any doubts feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a surfer enters one of my websites, I always assign a session to him. The session holds a couple infos, for example: agent, IP, language, date, … etc., and gets passed along via cookie or via GET (as parameter to each one of my pages).

Since I deal with a lot of image content, I started databasing my collection. Which basically means that for administration and clustering purposes, I am saving all my images to a SQL database which is multi-homed and spread accross several servers. One could argue if that is a smart thing to do, but we can argue that on another day and in another article.

I wrote a little script which is used throughout my site:

```
<img src="http://example.com/display.php?id=34" border="0" alt="" />
```

With an ever changing ID of course. That’s the part referencing my images in the database.
The following is the code from the script which I use to retrieve the image from the database:

```
<?php
$connection=@mysql_connect(...);

@mysql_select_db(...);

$query="SELECT mime, file FROM images 

WHERE id=".$_GET["id"];

$rawdb=@mysql_query ($query,$connection);

if($rawdb AND @mysql_num_rows($rawd-->0){

  $array=@ mysql_fetch_array($result);

  if (!empty($array["fileContents"])){

    // Output the MIME header

    header("Content-Type: ".$array["mime"]}");

    // Output the image

    echo $array["file"];

  }else{

    // something else...

  }

  @mysql_free_result($rawdb);

}else{

  // something else...

}

@mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

Since I already have a session for each user that comes to my website, I just added the following:

```
<img src="http://example.com/display.php?id=34&sid=383829" border="0" alt="" />
```

And implement a small session checkup in the script itself:

```
<!--
session_start();

if($_SESSION["is_known"]){

  // do database calls

}else{

  header("Location:http://mydomain.tld/dontsteal.html");

}

-->
```

The main advantage to my method is, that the session is entirely server side. A user can not rid himself off it, or fake information. Since I have a timeout and save all the necessary info (IP!) to validate against, it looks pretty perfect to me and fit my needs.

One of the setbacks here are resources and performance. But since I am not forcing you, you may test and evaluate. Hope that helps!

Comment: but if the person refreshes the page he will be shown error

Comment: Nice approach but involves too much resources and limits content to registered users only. Might be helpful for different situations.

Comment: That's for sure but for more security you need to use something like this!

Answer (score 0):

Create a php script which you use as src in the img tag.

In that script get the data from the image with `file_get_contents`. Then send the header with the right mime type. For example `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` Then output the data.